# Deleting property tags specified in Lwc meta cannot be deleted?

Tags: lightning-web-components, metadata, lightning-community-template

I have this sandbox env. i use for development, where I for a LWC component have added a
property tag while developing. I now want to remove this property tag, but cannot do so?

I get this error when I redeploy the LWC component without the `error` property tag.

```
 You can't remove the property tag(s) named 'error' specified in targetConfig lightningCommunity__Default.
```

I then tried to delete the ligthning component via

```
setup -> lightning component
```

which throws an error stating
Unable to Complete the Requested Change
Your changes could not be completed for the following reasons:

```
Reason  Section
The object you're trying to delete is in use on site {sitename}, which is under development.    Managed Content Resource

The object you're trying to delete is in use on site {sitename}, which is published.     
 Managed Content Resource
```

Managed content ressource does not lead to anything?

So how do I get rid of it?

Comment: The error means that this component is on a Digital Experience page somewhere. You'll have to find the page(s) using this component and remove the component from those pages. Try using [MetadataComponentDependency\(https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_api_objects_metadatacomponentdependency.htm) to determine the pages that use it.

Comment: Not sure I understand how i can search the dependency using this ?
I know the component name, can i somehow use that to filter it out?

Comment: @sfdcfox I managed to find the view, in which the component was previously used, via MetadataComponentDependency, and this https://salesforcecodex.com/salesforce/find-referenced-metadata-using-salesforce-dependency-api/

My problem now is that I don't understand why that is the case?
I pulled down the digital experience bundle, and looked though the view, but cannot  find the property i want to delete. It does not exist? 

so why does it show up as a dependcy? '